# When can $\sup_x$ and $\sup_y$ be swapped?

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

$f$ is a mapping from $X \times Y$ to $Z$.

$X$ and $Y$ are sets.

$Z$ is a set with $\sup$ defined ( I am not very sure how to formulate that. Is $Z$ required to have some total order?), and can be but not necessarily $\mathbb R$ (although $Z=\mathbb R$ is what I am considering, I also like to know more general).

Is it true that $$ \sup_x \sup_y f(x,y) = \sup_y \sup_x f(x,y) = \sup_{(x,y)} f(x,y)?$$

Thanks.

Comment: All you'd need to prove is $\sup_x \sup_y =\sup_{(x,y)}$, then you'd get $\sup_y \sup_x$ for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

Assume $z$ is an upper bound for $\{\sup_y\,f(x,y)\,:\,x\in X\}$, then as $z\ge \sup_y f(x,y)$ for all $x$, we get
$$z\ge f(x,y)$$
for all $x$ and $y$. 
Conversely, if $z$ is an upper bound for $\{f(x,y)\,:\,x\in X,\,y\in Y\}$, then again trivially $z\ge\sup_y f(x,y)$ for any $x$, hence $z\ge \sup_x\left(\sup_y f(x,y)\right)$.

So we find that the sets of upper bounds for $\{\sup_y\,f(x,y)\,:\,x\in X\}$ and for $\{f(x,y)\,:\,x\in X,\,y\in Y\}$ coincide, so their least element (the $\sup$) is the same.

Note that it works for any complete (semi-)lattice $Z$ (i.e. partially ordered set with all of its subsets having supremum).